# .NET async/await event debouncer/throttler

Tags: .net, async-await, throttling, debouncing

I am having troubles envisioning what an event throttler (aka a debouncer) would look like in .NET with `async/await`.

Consider the following code.

```cs
/// <summary>
/// A local, in-memory event throttler/debuouncer.
/// </summary>
public class EventThrottler
{
    private TimeSpan _delay = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);

    /// <summary>
    /// Begin a timer to release callers of "AwaitEvent".
    /// If a timer has already begun, push it back for the length of 5 seconds.
    /// This method should not block.
    /// </summary>
    public void TriggerEvent()
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Multiple people can await.
    /// Callers will be released exactly 5 seconds after the last call to "TriggerEvent".
    /// If no call is ever made to "TriggerEvent", consumers of "AwaitEvent" will wait, indefinitely (or until CancellationToken is triggered).
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="token"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public Task AwaitEvent(CancellationToken token)
    {
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

What approach should I use here?

A `ManualResetEvent` that all callers to `AwaitEvent` can wait for? Then, a `System.Timers.Timer` that gets reset after each call to `TriggerEvent`, which will eventually release the event?

Comment: See [Task.Delay](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.delay?view=netframework-4.7.2). Use that in combination with a cancellation token overload and you can reset the delay (or the execution of whatever it is your are executing if that is also Task based).

Comment: Thanks, I came up a solution using Task.Delay.

Comment: The timer is not necessary, you can do all of that with only Task.Delay which takes a time out value as parameter. In fact the whole class is not necessary, you can just use Task.Delay directly where you need to "throttle" the response.

Comment: I'm not seeing how I would integrate the "TriggerEvent" in your method. Maybe you can stub it out a little?

Comment: `async doSomethingAsync(CancellationToken ct) { await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), ct); await YourTaskAsync(ct); }` <= so wait 5 seconds and then do the next thing. Cancellation token is used to cancel the action from the calling code.

Comment: You aren't throttling or debouncing, you are just adding a delay.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.

```cs
public class EventThrottler
{
    private object _lock = new object();
    private CancellationTokenSource _cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    private Timer _timer;

    public EventThrottler(TimeSpan delay)
    {
        _timer = new Timer();
        _timer.Interval = delay.TotalMilliseconds;
        _timer.AutoReset = false;
        _timer.Elapsed += OnTimerElapsed;
    }

    public void TriggerEvent()
    {
        _timer.Stop();
        _timer.Start();
    }

    public async Task AwaitEvent(CancellationToken token)
    {
        CancellationTokenSource tokenSource;

        lock (_lock)
        {
            if (_cancellationTokenSource == null)
            {
                _cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
            }

            tokenSource = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(token, _cancellationTokenSource.Token);
        }

        try
        {
            await Task.Delay(Timeout.Infinite, tokenSource.Token);
        }
        catch (TaskCanceledException ex)
        {
            if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnTimerElapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        CancellationTokenSource tokenSource = null;

        lock (_lock)
        {
            if (_cancellationTokenSource != null)
            {
                tokenSource = _cancellationTokenSource;
                _cancellationTokenSource = null;
            }
        }

        if (tokenSource != null)
        {
            tokenSource.Cancel();
            tokenSource.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```